# C++ boost test can't test operator <

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I am having trouble with the Boost C++ unit testing framework.  Here is
the file someclass.h

```
class someclass {
   public:
      someclass(int a_x, int b_x);
      someclass();

      friend bool operator<(someclass& lhs, someclass& rhs);
      friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const someclass& sa);

   private:
      int a;
      int b;
};
```

Here is the file someclass.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;
using std::ostream;

#include "someclass.h"

someclass::someclass(int a_x, int b_x)
:a(a_x), b(b_x)
{
}

//-------------------------------------------------------

someclass::someclass()
{
}

//-------------------------------------------------------

bool operator<(someclass& lhs, someclass& rhs)
{
   return std::tie(lhs.a, lhs.b) < std::tie(rhs.a, rhs.b);
}

//-------------------------------------------------------
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const someclass& rhs)
{
   stream << "(" << rhs.a << "," << rhs.b << ")";
   return stream;
}
```

Here is the program to test it:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE test_someclass
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include <ostream>

using std::ostream;

#include "someclass.h"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( someclass_lt )
{
   someclass sa1(1,4);
   someclass sa2(1,5);
   someclass sa3(2,3);
   someclass sa4(2,4);
   someclass sa5(2,5);

   BOOST_TEST( sa1 < sa2 );
   BOOST_TEST( !(sa2 < sa1) );
   BOOST_TEST( sa1 < sa3 );
   BOOST_TEST( sa1 < sa4 );
   BOOST_TEST( sa1 < sa5 );
}
```

The file someclass.cpp compiles fine by itself, but when I try to compile the
whole thing together I get a huge set of error messages which read, in part,

```
In file included from testsomeclass.cpp:9:0:
someclass.h:6:19: note: bool operator<(someclass&, someclass&)
       friend bool operator<(someclass& lhs, someclass& rhs);
                   ^
someclass.h:6:19: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘someclass’ to ‘someclass&’
```

I have tried every way I can think of to correct this, to no avail.
I have also searched in stackoverflow.com and many other sites, to no avail.
Can someone tell me what's wrong and EXACTLY how to fix it?  Thanks.

Bruce

Answer (score 0):

You should use correct constness:

```
friend bool operator<(const someclass& lhs, const someclass& rhs);
```